# How to count number of instructions in code path?

Tags: java

Consider the following snippet.

```
        for (int i = targetIndex; i < totalInTarget; i++) {
            ++step;
            _KVPair kvp = target.get(i);

            if (previousKey == null) {
                ++step;
                currentKey = kvp.getKey();
                  ...
```

Is there a way for me to know number of instructions taken:

- Each iteration
- Each if/else decision

Without manually counting them with `++step`;

Comment: It appears what you really want is how many times a line is executed.  You can do this with code coverage tools without modifying the code.

Comment: This sounds somewhat like an X-Y question. Are you trying to ultimately achieve something specific, or just asking to know this particular factoid?

Comment: Peter, what tool would tell you how many times a line is executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, no.

You could use javap to show you the bytecode, but that doesn't translate directly to CPU instructions (if that's what you mean). The number of instructions will vary on whether it's interpreted or JIT'ed, how it's optimized and possibly other factors (GC options?).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at using [Javap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javap.html) to disassemble this into JVM instructions ?

Comment: How can output be used to compute total iterations/ decisions?

Comment: You'd need to determinehow many JVM instructions per line, and do some calculations. You can't determine native instructions, due to the JIT compilation mechanism