# data transferred in calling a user defined function

Tags: matlab, input, user-defined-functions, output, variadic-functions

I need to analyze a big source code.Code contains several function calls. 
Depending upon the computation and communication between function calls, i will need to figure out the best configuration scheme for the overall execution of the source code.

> According to me ,

Data communicated in calling a function(if it is on different machine,server etc)=Input Data Size+Output Data Size

for getting the input data size and output data size ,i think i should rewrite all functions to have variable number of inputs and variables outputs.

```
[varargout] samplefunction(varargin) {

FOR i=0:nargin
 inputdata=inputdata+sizeof(varargin(i));



% Do stuff here


}
```

isn't there a way to calculate size of cell array(varargin/varargout) directly in Matlab ?

or if u can suggest another approach to measure communicated data between function call ?

Comment: the idea is to access matlab workspace by using whos(var) ,bu problem is ,i don't have the actual variable name in the function body . Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A call to [`cellfun()` with string inputs](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html#zmw57dd0e73385_block) would be very fast:

```
sizes = [cellfun('size',varargin,1); cellfun('size',varargin,2)];
```

or

```
lenghts = cellfun('length',varargin);
```

or

```
numels  = cellfun('prodofsize',varargin);
```

Comment: sizes = [cellfun('size',varargin)] can i use this to obtain sum of sizes at once  ? or using sizes+= [cellfun('size',varargin,i)] in loop ? i will going to try it ,and will let you know soon . Do you have any other idea to measure extent of communication between function calls apart from focusing on input and outputs

Comment: or any approach which doesn't insist me to rewrite all functions in terms of variable number of inputs and outputs ?

Comment: sizes in the first line is giving the dimension :( and i need the data size in terms of Bits or Bytes :)

Comment: Then you need to use `s = whos`.

Comment: yes.. but in the function body , i don't have the name of actual variable.. the only thing i have is the formal one. . so there is no way to access the matlab workspace from the function body through the variable name or even it might not be able to the file having function defination ..any suggestion ?

Comment: Why do you need the name of the variable, anyways [`inputname()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/inputname.html). Can't you just loop for each content of `varargin`, assign it to `temp`, call `whos temp` and get the memory consumption?

Comment: yeah !! it was logical . i was slightly confused :)

Comment: But there is a point.. whos(varargin(1)) not working and if i hold the value in a new variable like temp= varargin(1) and then use s=whos(temp) ,then s.bytes is not the actual data size of the input.rather it the size of new variable.For me these two are differing significantly .I am getting 140 Bytes when it should be around 8 Bytes. Hope you got my point..And thanks for giving time !

Comment: I think , it is happening because varargin & varargout are defined in Matlab in terms of cell array and hence a an extra memory is consumed in holding the data in the cells index ?

Comment: You should assign only the content to the temporary variable, i.e. `varargin{ii}` (note the curly braces). And yes, a cell array imposes 112bytes of overhead.